# How to set permissions for SP2010 Server

Tags: 2010, permissions, security, active-directory, best-practices

I'm new to SharePoint 2010 and am creating numerous Publishing sites with workflows, each for a different department. Each department needs to have a few people assigned to be able to create pages, add/edit list items, etc., within that site. The sites are all based on the default master page (no modifications) and some custom page layouts.

The SharePoint server is tied to Active Directory. What's the best way to enable permissions on each site to the departments, keeping in mind that we might need some users to create/edit content while someone else reviews/approves the content via workflows?

In this scenario, our lists and page layouts are based on custom site columns and content types. Is it wise to open it up to non-IT people to create lists? What level of permissions do you usually give the departmental users?

Can you point me to some resources on this subject? Your guidance and help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You give people the permission they need to do their job.  The point of using WCM is that everyday users can create and publish web content without going through IT to get it done.  So if a few departmental users need to create web content, give them access to do so, train them on the process and you should be all set.  The content is going to be reviewed before it's published, so you'll be safe in that regard.

To permission the sites, add users to the SharePoint groups as necessary.  In a WCM environment, there are a lot of groups that are created for you.  If you're getting fine grained in your permissions with different approvers fr different sites, you'll need to create many groups to give rights to the areas so other departments aren't approving other departments content.